# Never expire facebook page and data access token

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I want to generate never expired facebook page and data access token. Following this
 [Never Expiring Facebook Page Access Token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53510296/never-expiring-facebook-page-access-token) I am able to
make facebook page never expired but data access will be expired after 3 months.Is there any way to make them all never be expired.

Please check the image

https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxmfB.png

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no way to avoid Data Access Expiry.

But with tasks performed using a page access token, you are likely not going to be affected much in the first place. As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/auth-vs-data/#data-access-expiration explains, there are a couple of permissions that do not expire.

`manage_pages` and `publish_pages` are on that list (plus a few other page / ads / insights related ones.)