# Google Sheet Facebook Lead Form integration does not updates with new leads

Tags: facebook, facebook-webhooks

I want to integrate the new Google Sheet CRM in order to get a Google Spreadsheet updated each time I receive a new lead from an Ad.

These are the steps I'm following.

[image: CRM selection]

[image: Google sign up]

[image: Click to new integration]

[image: Add the spreadsheet URL (not public) and select the form that I want to receive the leads (I only have one form)]

[image: Everything is fine. Click connect]

[image: Apparently everything is correct]

[image: Connected]

I can see the leads inserted in the spreadsheet until integration date, but the spreadsheet is not updated with the new leads afterwards.

I'm not a verified business, but I'm trying to pass the process. However, as far as I know, this shouldn't be a problem. In fact, a few months ago I was able to retreive myself the new leads and get notified via Webhooks, but as I'm not a verified business, it seems that I can't do it anymore.

I talked with Facebook support (here in Spain) and they don't have a clue of what I'm talking about. They are not technical in any way.

Anyone has faced this problem and found the solution?

Another solution for me would be to be able to create my own app just for my business, without the verification being mandatory (they don't approve my petitions but they don't tell me why, even though I send everything they ask me). Is this even possible?

Thanks a lot for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't able to make that CRM work, but I found a solution for being able to acquire my leads [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77217518/578379).